# Can I deploy a Contract to a readable address in a test environment?

Tags: nearprotocol

The readable address are talking about here is in the form of an "*.near."

```
    fn get_context(predecessor_account_id: AccountId) -> VMContext {
        VMContext {
            current_account_id: "alice.near".to_string(),
            signer_account_id: "bob.near".to_string(),
            signer_account_pk: vec![0, 1, 2],
            predecessor_account_id,
            input: vec![],
            block_index: 0,
            block_timestamp: 0,
            account_balance: 1_000_000_000_000_000_000_000_000_000u128,
            account_locked_balance: 0,
            storage_usage: 10u64.pow(6),
            attached_deposit: 0,
            prepaid_gas: 10u64.pow(18),
            random_seed: vec![0, 1, 2],
            is_view: false,
            output_data_receivers: vec![],
            epoch_height: 0,
        }
    }
```

I'm using the above context.

What should I do if I want to deploy NEP21 tokens to the address "token.alice.near"?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This testing environment does not do any real deployment. You can specify `token.alice.near` as the `current_account_id`, so [`near_sdk::env::current_account_id()`](https://docs.rs/near-sdk/2.0.0/near_sdk/env/fn.current_account_id.html) will report `token.alice.near` when you access it from your contract methods.